# devextreme dxSelectBox - How to select text when the widget is focused using Javascript

Tags: javascript, devextreme

I want to automatically select text on the widget when search is enabled, at this time whe I focus on the widget I just get the search text, and I have to delete everything manually. I only found the following code in [Devexpress support page](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t852946/selectbox-how-to-select-text-when-the-widget-is-focused), but it is for Angular (in Typescript):

```
onFocusIn(e: any) {  
      e.element.querySelector("input.dx-texteditor-input").select();  
}
```

How can I implement this on Javascript?

My best guess was

```
      onFocusIn: function(e) {
        e.component.option("input.dx-texteditor-input").select();
      }
```

Off course this didn't work. This is not the way to access the editor of the component.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the jQuery version of devextreme.
You need to access the `element` property in order to use `querySelector` like you did in your angular example.

This should work:

```js
$('#searchBox').dxSelectBox({
  dataSource: products,
  displayExpr: 'Name',
  valueExpr: 'ID',
  searchEnabled: true,
  showClearButton: true,
  onFocusIn(e) {
    e.element.get(0).querySelector("input.dx-texteditor-input").select();  
  }
}).dxSelectBox('instance');
```

In case you are implementing the select all functionality just to remove the input, there is a better way doing this.
Use the [`showClearButton`](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Components/dxSelectBox/Configuration/#showClearButton) property also shown in the code sample above.